# Magento error prevents me from flushing cache to fix error

Tags: magento

I have the error "Mage registry key "_singleton/my_observer" already exists" error which is preventing me from clearing the cache and getting the site working again. I had originally accidentally added a duplicate my_observer class to my config.xml which is what caused the initial problem, and I since removed both instances completely, but I still get the same error. I have removed all instances and mentions of my_observer from the site, but the error still keeps popping up (I use phpstorm to search the entire project for any mention, and it found none).

I have tried flushing the cache through a shell command, but I only get the error 'php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known'.

I have empties the var/cache folder and the var/session folder as well, to no avail.

I have cleared the cache in my browser, used another browser, and used incognito mode, all of which did not work either.

I know I basically need to flush the cache to make the site work again, but I basically can't flush the cache until I flush the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thank goodness I found an answer to my question. My cache is a Redis cache and I used the following commands to flush the cache through CLI (note, I had to install redis-tools in the CLI for this to work):

```
Pick one of the options below

    redis-cli FLUSHDB
    redis-cli -n DB_NUMBER FLUSHDB
    redis-cli -n DB_NUMBER FLUSHDB ASYNC
    redis-cli FLUSHALL
    redis-cli FLUSHALL ASYNC
```

You can find your DB number in app/etc/local.xml.

Here is my source:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-flush-redis-cache-and-delete-everything-using-the-cli/